# Firebase Cofiguration Open - Web App

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using firebase for a web app, the config which contains Api key and other credentials is open. I have written rules to prevent to write database, but i couldnt prevent them from registration, i have whitelisted some domains, but other than that domains are also accessible in creating users. I am converting this web app into android app and ioS app using cordova. is there any way to prevent user registration.

Comment: If you want to limit the number of users you'll have to do it manually. And if you want to prevent dos attacks. Using captcha would be a good approach.

Comment: config file is open, so if some one uses this config file to add users unnecessarily @rv7284

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to allow some users to register, but not others? I'm also assuming you want to use Google's built in registration system.

**First Method**

The fastest but probably hardest way to achieve this is to use firebase functions to whitelist a set of users in advance. Firebase functions can catch the request for sign-up then simply ignore it if it doesn't match your whitelisted addresses.

Of course you could use it to perform all sorts of other features too like sending it a request that allows sign-up for a short period of time. Anything that is possible through javascript.

Otherwise you'll be stuck creating your own sign-in method.

That, I think is the only way to prevent them from registration.

**Second Method**

If instead you wanted to allow signup but not allow access to the database you should be able to set the rules to "auth = (uid)" which will only allow those uids to write.

Again the same process can be achieved with firebase functions by allowing writing and such based on your set of uids.

Another method is firebase remote config conditions and  to achieve a similar effect. (I wouldn't suggest this however because it can create an unsafe client side authentication, or unnecessary steps to check for auth).

Something that I use which is similar is allowing full access to the database but using firebase functions to prevent deletion. This method allows users have full access but I can easily change their ability to write, move, or delete nodes whenever I want. Essentially, if it turns out that the firebase functions method is best suited for your situation, I can update my response to include a sample from my code.

**Third Method**

Some users of firebase instead use the database to store users and their credentials along with their profile data. So that when a user signs up, it instead will add a node to the database which can easily be accepted or denied by simple moving it, deleting it, or creating a key which dictates their permissions.

Good luck with firebase. Its features can often be somewhat hidden and hard to find. It might be useful to watch the full Google I/O presentation on youtube which explain its expansive repertoire in detail. It can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb2GZ3Bh4p8). I highly suggest this because it helped me better understand the features and (to be honest) all the ways I should have been using firebase (but wasn't).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my problem is if anyone has my config file, they would able to create their own phishing page and they can register, eventhough they dont have database access which will be prevented by rules, but i want to prevent registration from other domains. @Drei

Comment: Under authentication, in the SIGN-IN METHOD tab, you can change authorized domains.

Comment: i did that too but its still happening from other domains @Drei

Comment: It could be that because the config can be copied, the auth domain included in the file is also being copied. There really isn't a way around this other than some trickery with firebase functions. Yet, I'm intrigued; can you give me an example of how you tested access from other domains?

Comment: From other domain we can whitelist only the domains for OAuth for third party apps, but we cant do it for the normal registration @Drei

Comment: Ok, so in the general setting, you can see each apps information. Android has SHA and apple has the Bundle ID and App ID Prefix. In theory they prevent apps from access. However, considering you are using cordova, it might not apply. I also know that because it uses the google cloud platform, you might be able to find what you're looking for by clicking the setting cogwheel next to Overview. There you have access to the rest of google's authentication tools. From there, I don't have much more advice. If all else fails you may be forced to use custom authentication or firebase functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need absolute control on user registration, I think you should use `custom authentication`.That way, users will not be signing up on your Firebase instance directly, but you will be providing separate server APIs for the registration and login processes.

When a user signs in( that too, through your server API), you can issue her/him a `custom authentication token` which they can use to authenticate and access data on Firebase. You can read more about custom authentication [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

You can have a small NodeJS server that runs your registration logic. There you can disallow email that are undesirable.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)'s the documentation on creating custom authentication tokens from your server.